# Detect mous tabbed during shift key pressed

Tags: c#, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

Cant find a solution for detecting tabbed event through a pointer during the shift key ist pressed on the keyboard. There are only solutions with focus of the keyboard or focus of the mouse, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work. Just make sure that you set the `Grid`'s `Background` to `Transparent` or any color.

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="KeyboardExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:KeyboardExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid
        Background="Transparent"
        Tapped="RootGrid_Tapped" />

</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Input;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.System;
using Windows.UI.Core;

namespace KeyboardExample;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    static bool IsKeyDown(VirtualKey key)
    {
        return InputKeyboardSource
            .GetKeyStateForCurrentThread(key)
            .HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down);
    }

    private void RootGrid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsKeyDown(VirtualKey.Shift) is true)
        {
            // Your logic here...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this answer solves your issue, please accept it as the answer so we can close this session.